# MYSQL Delete Where Field is Not Part of Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table "groupdentlink" where I want to delete all the rows that weren't checked in a form.

In essence I want to perform a query like:

```
DELETE * FROM groupdentlink
WHERE group_id = 'a'
AND dentist_id IS NOT IN ARRAY 'b'
```

I think I could set a variable with a foreach loop and then keep adding the array values to it so I end up with:

```
DELETE * FROM groupdentlink
WHERE group_id = 'a'
AND dentist_id != 'D1'
AND dentist_id != 'D5'
AND dentist_id != 'D8'
```

...and so on.

But is this really the right/best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait, even that solution is throwing a syntax error... hmmm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM groupdentlink
WHERE group_id = 'a'
AND dentist_id NOT IN ('D1','D5','D8')
```

More info here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know I'm close now, but getting syntax error with this query: DELETE * FROM groupdentlink WHERE group_id = 'a' AND dentist_id NOT IN ('UTG1','UTG10','UTG100')

Comment: `DELETE * FROM` -> `DELETE FROM`. I didn't saw this as well :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute this query from a Zend Framework driven application please take in consideration the followings :

```
$where = sprintf('dentist_id NOT IN ("%s")', implode('", "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $array))); 
$this->sqlMapper->delete($where);
```

If you try . operator for concatenation purposes the query will result in a fatal error because of the quotes. So from my experience using htmlspecialchars or htmlencode along with . operator will only consume your time and patience. The use of sprintf is elegant, helps you keep your code clean.

And I think these observations apply to any application that makes use of php objects.

Answer (score 1):

New user to Stack Exchange, please forgive and instruct if I'm committing a faux pas.

The preceeding answer is incredibly dangerous, because it opens you up to SQL injection attacks.

Always use bind params.

Always use bind params.

Always use bind params.

Hint: if your query does not resemble "DELETE * FROM groupdentlink WHERE group_id = 'a' AND dentist_id IS NOT IN (?, ?, ?);" you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant, fully parametrized solution (using PDO):

```
$dentistIds = ['D1', 'D5', 'D8'];

$query = sprintf(
    "DELETE FROM online_order_shipping
           WHERE group_id = 'a'
             AND dentist_id NOT IN (%s)",
    implode(',', array_fill(0, count($dentistIds), '?'))
);

$stmtDelete = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmtDelete->execute($dentistIds);
```

The `implode` function strings `?` together with `,` without adding a comma in the end ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php#90555)). You could turn that into a function to make it more readable, otherwise the `sprintf` keeps it nice and tidy without ugly string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the statement `$str = rtrim($str, ",");` 
didnt remove the trailing comma giving rise to an 
error
I came up with this work around:

// string without quotes

```
$str = array_shift($array);
```

// string with quotes

```
$str = "'" . array_shift($array) . "'";
```

```
foreach ($array as $item)
{

    $str .= ", '" . $item . "'";

}
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here How I do it :

`assuming you have an array called $csvstocknumbers = ['0','1'];
 $stocknumbers = implode(",",$csvstocknumbers)  ; // make the content of the array in one string seprated by ,
 $deleteoldvehicles = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_name NOT IN

 ($stocknumbers ) ;";
 mysqli_query($con, $deleteoldvehicles);`

Answer (score -1):

You just need to join the ids with a comma:

```
$myarray = new array('D1', 'D5', 'D8');
$str = "";
foreach ($myarray as $item)
{
    $str .= $item . ",";
}
$str = rtrim($str, ",");

$query = "DELETE * FROM groupdentlink
             WHERE group_id = 'a'
             AND dentist_id NOT IN ($str)";
```

This will give you a query like this:

```
DELETE * FROM groupdentlink
    WHERE group_id = 'a'
    AND dentist_id IS NOT IN (D1, D5, D8);
```

If you need the quotes around the ids, then change the loop like this:

```
foreach ($myarray as $item)
{
    $str .= "'".$item . "',";
}
```

Comment: Darnit. Thanks for the help. I'm getting syntax errors with this query: DELETE * FROM groupdentlink
WHERE group_id = 'a'
AND dentist_id IS NOT IN ('UTG1','UTG10','UTG100')